# How to quickly search and print a large list of coefficients

Tags: coefficients

The following calculation is very fast.

```
k = 3 5 7 11 13 17; Short[Factor[x^k - 1], 5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

However, if the specific coefficients are expressed in red as follows, the calculation speed becomes too slow.

```
k = 3 5 7 11 13; Factor[x^k - 1] /. Times[x_Integer, y_] :> Times[If[x > 1 || x < -1, Style[x, Red, Bold], x], y] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This is much slower when I try to create a CDF with Manipulate.

```
Manipulate[ Short[Factor[x^n - 1], 2] /. Times[x_Integer, y_] :> 
Times[If[x > 1 || x < -1, Style[x, Red, Bold], x], y] // AbsoluteTiming, {n, 3 5 7 11 13 }, AppearanceElements -> None, ContinuousAction -> None ]
```

Q1. I want to find a way to speed up the calculation.

Q2. I have the following results expressed in Manipulate,
  I would like to display the screen to control the set size limit as shown above.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most fast version I found.

The trick is, to treat the result of "Factor" as a list.

```
k = 3 5 7 11*13  ; (fa13 = Factor[x^k - 1]);

(# /. (b_Integer /; b != 0 && b != 1 && b != -1)*x^a_ -> 
  Style[b, Red, Bold]*x^a) & /@ fa13 // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Even the conversion of factor up to 17 takes less than one second

```
k = 3 5 7 11*13*17  ; (fa17 = Factor[x^k - 1]);

(# /. (b_Integer /; b != 0 && b != 1 && b != -1)*x^a_ -> 
  Style[b, Red, Bold]*x^a) & /@ fa17 // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from the above output, coefficients and variables are reversed. Moreover, the red values are moved to the very end.

To preserve the original order:

```
form[m : Times[a_Integer, b_]] /; a > 1 :=
 Row[{Style[a, Red], Spacer@3, b}]

form[a_] := a

fac = Factor[x^165 - 1];

Unprotect[Plus];
ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless];

res = Map[form, fac, {2}];
```

An image of the last factor:

[image]

Don't forget to reverse the changes to `Plus`:

```
SetAttributes[Plus, Orderless];
Protect[Plus];
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.